# How to make a hover listener optional

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events, dom-manipulation

I've been having some difficulties, could someone point me in the right direction for this fiddle?

I need the div to animate on hover, but only when the `.isDown` class has been added to a different element by the click function.

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/BKFN3/2/)

```
$(".move").click( function(event){
event.preventDefault();
if ($(this).hasClass("isDown") ) {
    $(this).stop().animate({opacity:"0.5"}, 270);
    $(this).removeClass("isDown");
            
            //can put hover in here????
} else {
    $(this).stop().animate({opacity:"1"}, 300);
    $(this).addClass("isDown");
}
return false;
});

if ($(".move").hasClass("isDown")){

$(".funnyMOVE").hover(
   function() {
       $(this).stop().animate({top:"10px"},215);
   }, 
   function() {
       $(this).stop().animate({top:"0px"},230);
});

}
```

Comment: well on my website im using 1.10.2 only cause I want to use the most updated version and I use 10.1 on fiddle cause I see lots of fiddles that use version 7 and lots of things dont work from 7 to 10.1 ....is using 10.1 not good in your opinion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is working code:

I removed your code outside of the `.move` click and put this in it:

```
$(".fuckerMOVE").hover(function () {
    $(this).stop().animate({
        top: "10px"
    }, 215);
},
function () {
    $(this).stop().animate({
        top: "0px"
    }, 230);
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/BKFN3/3/)

The problem was that `if ($(".move").hasClass("isDown")){` was reached on document load, where this would have been false. My solution was just to apply the hover bind on the element directly when you are wanting it to be bound.

---

I actually just realized it looks like you were wanting to remove the bind if the `.move` is clicked again. If this is the case, you can move your bind into your `else` block and then add this to the `if` block:

```
$(".fuckerMOVE").off("mouseenter mouseleave");
```

The reason for `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` is that behind the scenes `hover()` sets listeners for these events.

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/BKFN3/27/)

Comment: @mike, I updated my post - noticed something that I didn't notice at first.

Comment: I appreciate it! Works perfectly and really helped me understand how to do this seriously!!

Answer (score 2):

Use the same condition inside the `hover` function. You are only binding the event in DOM ready based on the condition. So the event is never bound as the condition is `false` to start with.

```
$(".fuckerMOVE").hover(

function () {
    if ($(".move").hasClass("isDown")) {
        $(this).stop().animate({
            top: "10px"
        }, 215);
    }
},

function () {
    if ($(".move").hasClass("isDown")) {
        $(this).stop().animate({
            top: "0px"
        }, 230);
    }
});
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/BKFN3/5/)**

Comment: I gave the answer to smerny only cause he answered like a minute before and hes got a few less answers overall. Thanks very much I really appreciate it though. Thanks for the explanation too that really helps me understand this now!

Answer (score 1):

not sure if this is what you want.

http://jsfiddle.net/hvLA6/

```
$("#move").click( function(event){
event.preventDefault();
if ($(this).hasClass("isDown") ){
    $(this).stop().animate({opacity:"0.5"}, 270);
    $(this).removeClass("isDown");        
} else {
    $(this).stop().animate({opacity:"1"}, 300);
    $(this).addClass("isDown");
}

if ($("#move").hasClass("isDown")){
    $(".fuckerMOVE").hover(
       function() {
           $(this).stop().animate({top:"10px"},215);
       }, 
       function() {
           $(this).stop().animate({top:"0px"},230);
    });
}
return false;
});
```

CSS

```
div {
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
    background:black;
    position:relative;
}
#move {
    font-size:20px;
    background:pink;
}
```

Comment: see this is exactly how I thought it should work. Only thing is when you click the button again the div continues to hover...so the if statement isnt really working because the hover animation works even when the click button is adding / removing the class...thanks though!